# Which laptop should I buy

Tags: laptop, quiet-computing, silent

I am a normal laptop user (Linux). Most of my work is text editing, internet surfing, and movie watching. I want to buy a new laptop with a cost of 500 Euros. According to my work I do not think I need a super processor or GPU,
**but what I really need is a quiet laptop** (fan noise drives me crazy) and I am not sure how to check this before buying.

Maybe the [Acer Extensa 2511](https://www.ixsoft.de/cgi-bin/web_store.cgi?ref=Products/de/ACEX2511HW-i5200.html)?

Answer (score 2):

If you can find it in Europe, get the **[ASUS Laptop VivoBook E403SA-US21](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834234161&nm_mc=AFC-C8Junction&cm_mmc=AFC-C8Junction-PCPartPicker,%20LLC-_-na-_-na-_-na&cm_sp=&AID=10446076&PID=3938566&SID=)**.

This laptop is *fanless*. On top of that, it uses a solid-state drive instead of a typical spinner, so you won't even get access sounds out of this thing. Literally the only noise coming from this machine would be what you ask it to put through its speakers.

Does it perform? In my estimation, yes. Its quad core Pentium N3700, while comparatively weak, should be quite sufficient for all of your needs. 4gb is a bit on the low end these days, and apparently this cannot be upgraded, but since Linux isn't that much of a memory hog to begin with, I'm not too concerned. Even in the event of needing to use swap off the drive, it's a fast drive, so it wouldn't be the absolutely horrendous swap/page file thrashing of yesteryear. Intel HD graphics are well-supported under linux and should provide you with the graphical power to watch movies on the 1080p screen without a hiccup.

There are lots of little perks to like about this design as well. Because of the low-power CPU and storage solution, Asus reports you could expect up to 14 hours of battery life, which is really quite exceptional. It is also very lightweight and does have a USB-C port, which will probably be important later on for connectivity purposes.

I think it's the right machine for you. That said, this is not an uncommon design, so if you can find cheaper models with a similar design spec, I wouldn't hesitate to recommend those either.